# how to get real-time table size in MariaDB 10.1.10

Tags: mysql, mariadb, filesize

Now I want to get the real-time table size in MariaDB 10.1.10 of company, the old solution of sum(data_length + index_length) is not real_time.

I searched Google and found that only [percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/21/innodb-page-sizes-plans-and-ideas/) has a more comprehensive solution, but the database machine of company doesn't allow to use ssh to log in.

MariaDb 10.1.10 is eqauls to MySQL 5.6 which doesn't have FILE_SIZE in information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES.

So, none of the above solutions are feasible, is there any other way to get the real-time table size in MariaDB 10.1.10?

Comment: *I want to get the real-time table size* What size do you need in really? data file size? the size which is occupied by this file on disk? data size in the data file? Anycase see [`information_schema.tables`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-tables-table/), DATA_LENGTH+INDEX_LENGTH value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to get the real-time table size on disk, the DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH value in information_schema.tables doesn't refresh in real time.

[MySQL document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html#:~:text=Configuring%20Automatic%20Statistics%20Calculation%20for%20Persistent%20Optimizer%20Statistics) say it was refresh when a table undergoes changes to more than 10% of its rows. but the document also say you can use **analyze table** to refresh data_length and index_length manually.
Now I think I have found my solution.

Comment: *I want to get the real-time table size on disk* MySQL cannot retrieve this data from the filesystem - it have no instruments which deals with OS and its FS. Search for such user-defined loadable function and register it on your server (or create your own). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-loadable.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-functions.html *the document also say you can use analyze table to refresh data_length and index_length manually* This is too expensive an operation.

Comment: Thank you for your careful answer, I think I also need to test if it works without affecting other script.

Comment: For disk size there is [this plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/disks-plugin/). It wasn't in 10.1.10 however its quite plausible that the shared library from a later 10.1 version is install-able.